# How can I insert an image into the clipboard using a terminal or bash script?

Tags: bash, clipboard, screenshot, xclip

I'm making a custom script that uses ImageMagick to take screenshots because I deleted the original application and wanted to do a custom one.

```
#! /bin/sh.
cd magickScreenshots/
ls -v | cat -n | while read n f; do mv -n "$f" "$n.jpg"; done 
import /home/alnexus/magickScreenshots/screenshot.jpg -quality 100 -trim
```

What that does is, it goes into the magickScreenshots folder, then renames everything to numbers, and it then uses ImageMagick to take a screenshot (I have to select an area for it to screenshot). The problem is, it only saves the image as `screenshot.jpg` in that folder (by the way the second line is just so that it renames all files and the new screenshot.jpg doesn't replace the old one, I want to keep all screenshots every session, they all get deleted when the computer starts up). I want to make it so that the `screenshot.jpg` file is automatically inserted into my clipboard. I tried some stuff but they all only copied the directory from the image, not the image itself (I had used the xclip command only). I've searched a lot and nothing worked, I even tried xclip-copyfile and it didn't seem to work, though I didn't mess with it very much

## EDIT

I tried `xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png ~/magickScreenshots/screenshot.jpg` and it did work on WhatsApp Web, but not on the Discord Desktop Linux app :(

Comment: its a image/jpeg not image/png

Comment: using image/jpg doesn't work at all. Only image/png

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, depending on `imagemagick` (`import`) and `xclip`:

```bash
sleep 1; import /tmp/ss.png; xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png </tmp/ss.png
```